# Bazel re-export headers in a cc_library from it's dependencies to pass `layering_check`

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I'm trying to Bazel-wrap a vendor-provided SDK for an embedded project. Part of that SDK includes a hardware abstraction layer (HAL), which has a set of identically named C headers and sources, separate for each part supported by the vendor. I was hoping to be able to create targets for each part, and then use `select` to include them into a *meta-target*, which always choses the right dependency, based on the chosen `platform`. However, depending on the meta-target is not equivalent: Because of the indirection, the HAL headers are not considered properly depended on, and thus will fail the `layering_check`. Is there a way to explicitly re-export the headers of its dependencies in the meta-target?

Sketch:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "hal_part_A",
    hdrs = ["part_A/hal_regs.h"],
    strip_include_prefix = "part_A/",
    target_compatible_with = ["//part:part_A"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "hal_part_B",
    hdrs = ["part_B/hal_regs.h"],
    strip_include_prefix = "part_B/",
    target_compatible_with = ["//part:part_B"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "hal",
    deps = select({
        "//part:part_A": [":hal_part_A"],
        "//part:part_B": [":hal_part_B"],
    }),
    # <- add in some 'magic' way to re-export the headers declared by the dependencies
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    deps = [":hal"],
)
```

If the source file `main.c` tries to include `hal_regs.h` provided by the HAL, bazel complains with `Compiling main.c failed: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//:main': 'part_A/hal_regs.h'` (assuming a platform using `//part:part_A` was selected), because `//:main` doesn't directly depend on `hal_part_A`, which exposes that header.

Is there a way to tell bazel that `hal` should re-export the headers exported from it's dependencies?

Workarounds that are suboptimal:

- Not using any meta targets like `hal`: Instead `main` could directly depend on a `select` linking to the corresponding HAL implementations. Disadvantage: The `select` logic needs to be copied to every dependant.
- Explicitly re-exporting all relevant headers from the meta target: The meta target could have explicit `hdrs = select(...)`, again listing all the headers. Things like `strip_include_prefix` complicate this, but can probably be solved. Still, suboptimal due to the duplication between the implementation targets and the meta target.

Comment: Turns out, the error-message I did observe is indeed not related to `layering_check` (which wasn't even enabled), but due to an issue in bazel: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14346. While it's closed, the bug persists for anything non obj-C. The question and accepted answer however still stands when that bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For quick and dirty... and probably correct to use in this instance, scroll to the bottom for using `alias` instead of wrapping library.

---

Something else isn't probably right, `cc_library` dependencies should be transitive... and as a matter of fact I took your example... filling in few blanks (adding trivial source examples and defined platforms providing `constraint_value` `//part:part_A` and `//part:part_B`) leaving your `BUILD` file intact... and it "does work":

```
$ bazel run main --platforms //part:A
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.053s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/main
PartA

$ bazel run main --platforms //part:B
INFO: Build option --platforms has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (0 packages loaded, 162 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.181s, Critical Path: 0.05s
INFO: 4 processes: 2 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/main
PartB
```

So, perhaps try to debug around a little: platform resolution, `select()` results and even C sources themselves... in fact...

Tracing back to your question and the reported failure complaining about... Well, I suspect the problem is how stuff got included? Since `strip_include_prefix = "part_A/"` for part_A (for instance) was used, you should no longer say:

```
#include "part_A/hal_regs.h"
```

but just:

```
#include "hal_regs.h"
```

I would presume by some coincidence (and perhaps a little oddity of tree layout) and the fact the sandbox isn't as hermetic as one would sometimes tend to hope and believe (RBE setup is a good way to test the assumptions and expose accidental leaks with much higher probability)... Preprocessor still managed to find `hal_regs.h` searching for `part_A/hal_regs.h`... but bazel (correctly here) detected this as undeclared dependency (which I think is where / what your error is emitted from / for).

---

I may have assumed too much about the context / setup, sorry about that. One quick hack (workaround) that comes to mind (regardless of exact mode of failure) would be to provide macro for the HAL selection, to make the first option in your question a little more palatable. E.g. something like `hal.bzl`:

```
def hal_deps():
    return select({
        "//part:part_A": [":hal_part_A"],
        "//part:part_B": [":hal_part_B"],
    })
```

And then consume like:

```
load(":hal.bzl", "hal")
...
cc_library(
    name = "hal",
    deps = [...] + hal_deps(),
)
```

For the less quick (and probably more correct) answer now considering a little more understanding of the context. This really is a question about `layering_check` feature and how it generates "intermediate" module maps... namely in this case it would do for instance something like this for `//:hal` target:

```
module "//:hal" {
  export *
  use "//:hal_part_A"
  use "crosstool"
}
extern module "//:hal_part_A" "../../../bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/hal_part_A.cppmap"
extern module "crosstool" "../../../external/local_config_cc/module.modulemap"
```

Which would not make LLVM happy when `main.c` grabs stuff from what is here would be another hop `"//:hal_part_A"` without (generated) `//:hal` asking for re-export.

This may be relatively young feature and could still see more development (incl. new API to define such use cases)? ATM I suspect this would me diving into it one-self and extending it (trying to upstream the changes).

---

One more update... and of course another very obvious (that I've missed so far) but possibly viable in this instance workaround, use `alias` to `select()` instead of a wrapping `cc_library`:

```
alias(
    name = "hal",
    actual = select({
        "//part:part_A": ":hal_part_A",
        "//part:part_B": ":hal_part_B",
    }),
)
```

This used to be a bit more problematic when dealing with `constraint_value`, but seems to be OK now... I suspect at least since bzl 5 (or 6?).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! May I assume that you are running with gcc? The `layering_check` causing this problem apparently is only supported using clang, and not on windows, as mentioned somewhere in the text to the documentation of [`cc_library`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library)

Comment: Library dependencies *are* indeed transitive, but bazel tries to prevent you from including "private" headers directly. Only headers publicly exposed (using `hdrs = ...`) by direct dependencies are considered accessible. This seems to be called the `layering_check` and is not consistently enforced.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I may have assumed too much here... I've tried this (quick setup) with auto-resolved cc_toolchain which ends up being GCC on my Linux host.... I'll add one more alternative option to the answer momentarily.

Comment: @burnpanck And of course after running in every direction... a fairly trivial and obvious (if still considered workaround) option could be an `alias`. I am a big fan of iterative approach with many side tracks.  Look, a squirrel! :)

Comment: I'm still very new to bazel, so I wasn't aware of the `alias`. Thanks a lot for pointing it out, seems like an exact fit for the purpose! Relieved that I don't have look into module maps, of which I don't know anything at all.

Comment: YW. In this case, I guess `alias` is actually the way to go. That said, you've asked an interesting question and it still has its merit. I have to admit, I've not until today played with `layering_check` probably because I actually have relatively little exposure to LLVM in day to day stuff.

Comment: Right, `alias` is not the right way in case the meta library is really supposed to bundle multiple libraries as opposed to just selecting an implementation. A good example might be if you tried to declare a `boost-all` library.